# Setting value to null using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an Id City on page which is basically a model property. I want to set it as null. I am trying this to achieve it:

```
$("#City").val(null);
```

But it is not setting the value to null.

Comment: By "it" do you mean the value of the element, the innerHTML of the element, or the ID of the element?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You don't set an elements value to `null`, as HTML has no concept of `null`, `undefined` etc, you remove the attribute, or better yet, set it to an empty string:

```
$("#City").val("");
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are trying to set/remove Id

```
$("#City").attr("id","");
```

or use   [removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

If you are trying to set the value inside that ,

```
$("#City").val("");
```

Answer (score 3):

Using normal javascript , try using `setAttribute` method ,

```
document.getElementById("City").setAttribute("value" , "");
```

or without using the `setAttribute` method,

```
document.getElementById("City").value = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove Id using `jQuery` `prop()` or `attr()` methods like this :

```
$('#City').prop('id', null);
```

or like this :

```
$('#City').attr('id', null);
```

Just in case :

[jQuery Documentation for prop() method](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

[jQuery Documentation for attr() method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)